# Current User's object is NULL in Symfony controller when I do login from phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit, symfony

I have the login function for PHPUnit and use it for authorization as test user.

```
private function logIn(Client $client)
{
    $session = $client->getContainer()->get('session');

    /** @var User $user */
    $user = $client->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getRepository('DWDAdminBundle:User')->find(1);
    //Here I have user object

    $firewall = 'main';
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $firewall, ['ROLE_ADMIN']);
    $client->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
    $session->set('_security_'.$firewall, serialize($token));
    $session->save();

    $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
    $client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
}
```

In tested action have this code:

```
$checkResult = $this->get('dwd.service.coupon')->checkCoupon(
            $coupon,
            $request->query->all(),
            $this->getUser()->getPortalId()
            // Here $this->getUser returned NULL
        );
```

Here somehow function getUser() returned Null although I've authorized my test user in setUp() of test

```
    public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->client = static::createClient();
    $this->logIn($this->client);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that repository return user object not an array? Shouldn't be `findOne()`?

Comment: @malcolm Yep, it returns the object. 
http://prntscr.com/cdad5q

Comment: I have the same problem, have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Is the tested action under the same firewall?

Comment: Yes, I use 'main' firewall